# Highchart columnrange with scrollbar

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using the columnrange type from Highcharts-more. The default data labels formatter puts the low / high data at both ends of the range, which is nice.

but when I use scrollbar,high labels don`t move Follow scroll,
How do I setting,to use scrollbar in columnrange chart?

example:[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/103110208/wamnqybr/1/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'columnrange',
    inverted: true
},

title: {
    text: 'Temperature variation by month'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Observed in Vik i Sogn, Norway, 2017'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        max:4,
        scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
        }
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Temperature ( °C )'
    }
},

tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: '°C'
},

plotOptions: {
    columnrange: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{y}°C'
        }
    }
},

legend: {
    enabled: false
},

series: [{
    name: 'Temperatures',
    data: [
        [-9.9, 10.3],
        [-8.6, 8.5],
        [-10.2, 11.8],
        [-1.7, 12.2],
        [-0.6, 23.1],
        [3.7, 25.4],
        [6.0, 26.2],
        [6.7, 21.4],
        [3.5, 19.5],
        [-1.3, 16.0],
        [-8.7, 9.4],
        [-9.0, 8.6]
    ]
}]

});
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, I would try reporting it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues. If you do, have a look at how the other bug reports are formatted, since reporting in the proper format will get you a response much quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Highcharts bug, which is already fixed in the master branch and will be published in version 7.0.2. In the meantime you can use the code from master branch:

```
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/master/highstock.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

or the older Highcharts version:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/6/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/6/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cqzn0tu3/

Highcharts file service: https://code.highcharts.com/